# Add new lines to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have successfully get content from the database and output the results in JSON. But I want to add a text that doesn't exists in the database and it's here I'm stuck.

```
$statement = $sql->prepare("SELECT data_filename,
                                   data_filetype,
                                   data_uniqid,
                                   data_description,
                                   data_coordinates,
                                   exif_taken,
                                   exif_camera,
                                   exif_camera_seo,
                                   exif_resolution,
                                   exif_sensitivity,
                                   exif_exposure,
                                   exif_aperture,
                                   exif_focallength,
                                   is_downloadable,
                                   is_notaccurate,
                                   allow_fullsize

                            FROM photos
                            WHERE data_filename = 'P1170976'");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($results);

echo $json;
```

That code gives me

`[{"data_filename":"P1170976","data_filetype":"JPG","data_uniqid":"","data_description":"","data_coordinates":"","exif_taken":"0000-00-00","exif_camera":"","exif_camera_seo":"","exif_resolution":"","exif_sensitivity":"0","exif_exposure":"","exif_aperture":"","exif_focallength":"","is_downloadable":null,"is_notaccurate":null,"allow_fullsize":null}]`

Which is correct of course but if I add these 2 new lines under `$json = json_encode...` I'm getting `null`.

```
$newdata = array('test' => 'just testing');
$json[] = $newdata;
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Put those lines BEFORE json_encode().

Comment: Before you convert results into json you can append that array.

Comment: Many thanks :) `null` have disappear now

Comment: $json is going to be a **STRING**... you can't push a new value onto it. You should push the value onto the original $results, **THEN** json_encode. never deal with the json string, always work the original (or resulting) native datastructure before/after encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode()` returns a string, so you can’t handle it as an array, i.e. add elements to string.

As noted in comments, you need to add those lines before `json_encode()` or decode it back to array using `json_decode()`, then apply the lines and then back `json_encode()`.

Example about usage of `json_encode` and `json_decode`:

```
$array = array("this" => array("will" => array("be" => "json")));
$string = json_encode($array); // string(31) "{"this":{"will":{"be":"json"}}}"

// ...

$array2 = json_decode($string); // now it’s same array as in first $array
$array2["new"] = "element";
$string2 = json_encode($array2);
var_dump($string2); // string(46) "{"this":{"will":{"be":"json"}},"new":"string"}"
```

Comment: Oh. Okey. How can I make the JSON into an array then?

Comment: Thanks! Can you add an example on how I can accomplish this? I have a hard time to see how new things (which this is to me) will end up :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren I made an answer about it :p

Comment: @lemondrop Yea and it's there I have a hard time to figure it out how the final code should be :/ I have tried but it's hard

Comment: @ErikEdgren: lemondrop’s way is better for you if possible. If absolutely needed, you can use that trick I showed (added example)

Comment: @Smar Your example worked perfectly! But how is lemondrop's code better than yours?

Comment: @ErikEdgren he meant the top example I have, it dosent have to decode the json and then re-encode it. Thats just repetitive. But I suppose if you need to its acceptable. Also my second example pretty much matches his except I didnt put a key in the [] which I guess is why it didnt work.

Comment: @lemondrop Ok. His example works better than yours :/ :) Your examples only gives me `null`. The code will be using on a kinda popular website so it would be nice to use the fastest way possible and I'm guessing it's your first example :)

Comment: @ErikEdgren yea only like a millisecond faster I guess, if you are really intrested run a speed test on it (do the specified operation 1000ish times, record speed of both)

Comment: @lemondrop Oh. So the differences isn't that much. I don't even know how to speed test it :P

Comment: Actually, if your json is more than few array elements, the speed difference is *very* big. PHP’s JSON encoding/decoding is so slow that I’ve started to wonder whether it is implemented with PHP instead of C...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newdata = array('test' => 'justtesting');
$results[] = $newdata;
$json = json_encode($results);
```

or if you definately need it after its encoded:

```
$json = json_encode($results);
//lots of stuff
$jarray = json_decode($results, true);
$newdata = array('test' => 'justtesting');
$jarray[] = $newdata;
$json = json_encode($jarray);
```

Comment: @ErikEdgren Yea I forgot a true on the json_deocde thing, that makes it output an array not object.

Comment: I'm getting `null` even if `true` is there :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren What are you getting null from?

Comment: I don't know. It only returns `null` instead of the data on both of your examples